# How can I use pdf.js with CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, pdf.js

I am trying to integrate CefSharp and pdf.js into a C# application.

I got CefSharp working easily, but am having trouble using pdf.js to load PDFs. It works if I load pdf.js using the bundled viewer.html, but only if it is hosted in the same place as my PDF.

Is it possible to load the Chrome extension into CefSharp within my application?
I tried loading it with the command line parameters but it didn't seem to do anything:

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["--user-data-dir"] = "C:\\...\\chromium";
settings.CefCommandLineArgs["--load-extension"] = "C:\\...\\PDF-Viewer_v1.5.294";
```

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Comment: Is there a reason your not using the built in pdf viewer?

Comment: Because if you click a link in the PDF and then navigate back it doesn't keep your position in the document, but pdf.js does.

Comment: You'll have to manually disable the internal `PDF Viewer` and work out a way to manually load `pdf.js`, `CEF` does not yet implement extensions, you can track the progress at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions

Comment: For future reference here's an example of setting a command line argument see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/53/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L69

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get pdf.js to load through CefSharp and in the end decided to host it on the same server that is hosting my PDFs.